# SQL set vs select giving different results when using date/char

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble converting/editing dates in MySQL, probably be easiest if I show my issue:

INPUT:

```
declare @from_dattim2 datetime

set @from_dattim2 = (select dateadd(day,-30,'2011-07-18'))

print @from_dattim2
```

OUTPUT:

```
Jun 18 2011 12:00AM
```

which makes sense, then...

INPUT:

```
declare @from_dattim2 datetime

set @from_dattim2 = (select dateadd(day,-30,'2011-07-18'))

print @from_dattim2

select convert (datetime, @from_dattim2, 121)
```

OUTPUT:

```
2011-06-18 00:00:00.000
```

This is the output I want however it doesn't seem to work when I try to set my variable:

INPUT:

```
declare @from_dattim2 datetime

set @from_dattim2 = (select dateadd(day,-30,'2011-07-18'))

set @from_dattim2 = convert (datetime, @from_dattim2, 121)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Jun 18 2011 12:00AM
```

Any ideas how I can set my variable to the format yyyy-mm-dd etc rather than Jun 18 etc?

Answer (score 1):

Convert doesn't cause the datetime to be stored in a different manner. It only affects the formatting when output.

So you simply need to store it as a datetime and, when you select the data, thats when you do the convert() to the desired formatting.

Comment: Ahaa I see, this makes sense! The only problem is that I want it as a variable to be able to reference it a lot of times later on. This is clearly possible but quite long winded. Any slicker ideas? - thanks for the help!

Comment: You could try creating a view over your table and, instead of the date column, you'd use `convert(...) as date`. Or, you can create a function `fnFormattedDate` and have it return the date as a varchar converted to your desired format.

Comment: I fear it will be even more long winded as I would need to convince several people it's a good idea to let me create a view or function in the production environment as I work with a one day old copy which is refreshed every night. Think I might go for convert with each reference as it does seem to be the easiest way. Many thanks for your help - that's a handy one to know!